# How to test JpaRepository using main class instead of test class or controller in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, repository

Say i have a repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

If i want to test out what the result will be (using System.out.println)
I know only one way:

Make a Controller class like so:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hey")
class Controller{

@Autowired
UserRepository repository;

@GetMapping()
public void hey(){
System.out.println(repository.findAll());
}
}
```

And then i have to start up the SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}


surf to localhost:8080/hey
```

And only then i see on the console what the result is.

This is so cumbersome and time-consuming, especially when the spring boot app is heavy and takes a long time to load.

What i would have loved to do is to comment out the springbootapplication and just make a temporary class that i run from the main class and print the results that way. That is so much faster.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
          new Temp().go();
    }
}

Class Temp{

@Autowired
UserRepository repository;

public void go(){
System.out.println(repository.findAll());
}
}
```

This isn't possible as its an interface and it asks you to implement every single method it has. How can i just print the results on the console of a repository without having to use controller ?

Comment: which kind of test do you want to implement? if unit test you should mock. If you want to perform an integration test you should set up the context with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) public TestClass`

Comment: I dont want to test anything, i just wanna see what the results are on the console log. Really i just want to System.out.println it

Answer (score 3):

As you mentionned if you comment `SpringApplication.run` Spring DI won't work because the Spring context is not yet configured with required beans.

What you can do to achieve your goal, first you need to keep `SpringApplication.run` and you can inject the repository as follows in your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App{

    public static UserRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public App(UserRepository repository) {
        App.repository= repository;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        System.out.println(repository.findAll());
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI the `@Autowired` is not needed

Comment: @Autowired is necessary in this case to get the repository instance with Spring and then assign it to the static field. It won't work without it.

Comment: Nope with for example spring-boot 2.7.2 just declaring the constuctor is enough. I don't know from what version this feature is avaiable

Comment: @Pp88 Thank you very much, new thing to learn :)